# yt-dlp not downloading all videos from channel in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, download, yt-dlp

I'm trying to download all 608 videos from this channel (https://www.youtube.com/@EndoJunts). However, when I use `yt-dlp` to download the channel, I only see 594 videos. This is the argument I used

```
yt-dlp -P D:\music\RapYoutube\EndoJunts -f 233 https://www.youtube.com/@EndoJunts
```

I've noticed the same issue with trying to download other Youtube channels as well. How can I ensure that every single video from a channel is downloaded?

Comment: What makes you think there are more than 594 public videos on that channel?

Comment: Youtube doesn't differentiate public and private/unlisted videos in their Playlist counts. Put a video in your Watch Later, then set that video to Private, and see what happens.

Comment: try youtube-dl instead

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this issue a lot nowadays and I may have a workaround after bashing my head against the keyboard for an hour. The channel you linked also didn't give me all 608 videos at first. When I loaded the playlist link at:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UU2_YZ1uugYThiNvz2Hbwl_Q and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxEYizMTkT4&list=UU2_YZ1uugYThiNvz2Hbwl_Q&index=608

yt-dlp then reported all 608 videos when passing https://www.youtube.com/@EndoJunts

You can also see 608 videos in all in that master playlist. For channels I've tried, I am sometimes like 20-30 videos off of the total listed on the channel page, but get all/most of them using this method. It's definitely YouTube's fault and not yt-dlp's.

Try loading those playlist link pages, scrolling all the way to the bottom, and clicking on a video or two. Hopefully the regular channel link will start working then. If it doesn't, just pass that first playlist link and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube lists private/unlisted videos in the Playlist counts, but does not allow access to these videos for viewing or access using tools such as yt-dlp. For this reason, the count of videos in a playlist that you see in the Youtube UI may not correspond to the number of videos yt-dlp can retrieve.

The most likely explanation for what you are seeing is that some videos in the playlist in question are private. The only way to know for sure is to look at a list of the videos in the playlist and compare that with the list of videos yt-dlp downloaded.

You could also build a script using yt-dlp that exports a list of all the videos it can access before it downloads them, and then goes through that list a second time, downloading each. This would have the benefit of giving you a log of the videos available and those downloaded and showing any errors experienced during the process.